# PHAR archive internals

Tags: php, phar

I'm developing a plugin for 7-Zip that will allow users to open and modify phar archives. But I don't fully understand the file format. The [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.fileformat.phar.php) describes the "Length of manifest in bytes (1 MB limit)" field. And I can't understand what this field is. What manifest is documentation talking about? How to calculate the correct value of this field when saving the phar file?

(The question is indirectly related to the php tag, but I think only php developers can answer.)

Comment: The manifest is the list of files in the archive. The length is the combined number of bytes taken by all of the files in the manifest.

Comment: @kmoser Thanks! Now everything is clear. But in my test this field also includes the size of the header without the size of the field itself. Anyway, could you create an "official" answer so I can accept it? Also, do you know where can I find phar samples that have serialized metadata and that have the files compressed with deflate and bzip2?

Comment: I've posted my comment as an answer. Not sure where you can find sample compressed phar files, but why not use [Phar::compress()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.compress.php) to create your own?

Comment: @kmoser The problem is that I am not a php developer. And I have nothing to do with web development. The purpose of writing my plugin is brain training.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manifest is the list of files in the archive. The length is the combined number of bytes taken by all of the files in the manifest.